# Effects coding for categorical variables with interactions in lavaan?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am interested in translating lm-syntax to lavaan, particularly I am after an **effects-coded** interaction between a **factor x numeric** variable when the factor has **> 2 levels**. (Reminder: [effects-coding](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-effect-coding/) is an alternative to dummy-coding categorical variables such that the codes are -1, 1, and 0.)

Below you see a minimal example (meaningless). You see lm (linear regression) syntax and then the corresponding lavaan syntax (regression part). It works for a regression without interactions but not with the interaction.

First consider an interaction-free regression with effects-coded factors.

**This works**

```
library(lavaan)
# Use iris data as minimal example
# 
# 1. Linear regression model
# Change contrasts to effects-coding
contrasts(iris$Species) <- contr.sum(3)
# Linear regression
lmmodel <- Sepal.Length ~ Species # the regression model
lmfit <- lm(lmmodel, iris) # fit it

# 2. SEM
# first, re-code the factors
iris$s1 <- contrasts(iris$Species)[iris$Species, 1] # Numeric and effects-coed
iris$s2 <- contrasts(iris$Species)[iris$Species, 2] #     - " -
semmodel <- 'Sepal.Length ~ s1 + s2' # the SEM model
semfit <- sem(semmodel, iris) # fit it

# 3. Compare the coefficients lm vs. sem, should be equal (and are equal)
cbind(coef(lmfit)[-1], coef(semfit)[-length(coef(semfit))])
#                 [,1]        [,2]
# Species1 -0.83733333 -0.83733330
# Species2  0.09266667  0.09266664
```

**Here is how I do it with the interaction**
Where am I going wrong?

```
# 1. Linear regression w/ interaction
lmmodel <- Sepal.Length ~ Species + Species:Sepal.Width
lmfit <- lm(lmmodel, iris)

# 2. SEM
iris$s3 <- as.numeric(iris$Species=='virginica') # Code third species
iris$s1_w <- iris$s1 * iris$Sepal.Width # Numeric interaction
iris$s2_w <- iris$s2 * iris$Sepal.Width #      - " -
iris$s3_w <- iris$s3 * iris$Sepal.Width #      - " -"
semmodel <- 'Sepal.Length ~ s1 + s2 + s1_w + s2_w + s3_w'
semfit <- sem(semmodel, iris)

# 3. Compare the coefficients lm vs. sem
cbind(coef(lmfit)[-1], coef(semfit)[-length(coef(semfit))])
#                                     [,1]       [,2]
# Species1                      -0.7228562 -0.7228566
# Species2                       0.1778772  0.1778772
# Speciessetosa:Sepal.Width      0.6904897  0.6904899
# Speciesversicolor:Sepal.Width  0.8650777  0.8650779  <----- equal
# Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width   0.9015345  2.4571023  <----- not equal
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? It is not clear to me. I cannot see any lavaan package and why the Length should be a latent variable ?

Comment: Hello! Thanks, here you go: `sem()` is a lavaan function, `semmodel` in the code is lavaan syntax. I am trying to model the regression "Sepal.Length ~ Species + Species:Sepal.Width" in lavaan.

Comment: PS: the code is a minimal example. My question concerns setting up the model correctly w/ effects coding. The coefficients from `lm` should equal `sem` coefficients (see, #2 https://psu-psychology.github.io/r-bootcamp-2018/talks/lavaan_tutorial.html). In my example2, a coefficient differs. It seems to be the case, that the correct coefficient (call it `b*`) is equal to `b - c - d` (`b` = s3_w effect, `c` = s2_w effect, `d` = s1_w effect). This seems right, considering the factor is effects-coded. What I would love to know is how to make lavaan produce the right coefficient (example: 0.9015)

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to understand why just this line is not equal: # Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width   0.9015345  2.4571023  <----- not equal correct ? Have you tried asking on the google groups as well ?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm after!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `lavaan`, you simply did not code correctly the contrasts the `Virginica Species`:

[image]

From row 101 to 150 you should have `0,0,1`, i.e.:

```
iris[101:150,"s2_w"] <- 0
iris[101:150,"s1_w"] <- 0
```

Rerun the original code:

```
semmodel <- 'Sepal.Length ~ s1 + s2 + s1_w + s2_w + s3_w'
semfit <- sem(model = semmodel, data = iris, estimator="ml")

# 3. Compare the coefficients lm vs. sem
cbind(coef(lmfit)[-1], coef(semfit)[-length(coef(semfit))])
```

And check:

```
(¬_¬)# 3. Compare the coefficients lm vs. sem
(¬_¬)cbind(coef(lmfit)[-1], coef(semfit)[-length(coef(semfit))])
                                    [,1]       [,2]
Species1                      -0.7228562 -0.7228563
Species2                       0.1778772  0.1778772
Speciessetosa:Sepal.Width      0.6904897  0.6904898
Speciesversicolor:Sepal.Width  0.8650777  0.8650778
Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width   0.9015345  0.9015345
```